Slow throughput when iptables is running (10GbE)
When iptables is running the throughput on the 10GbE gets slowed down and I have no idea why.
Gentoo Linux with Kernel 6.6.21
CPU: Intel Xeon E5-1650v4
~#@❯ iperf3 -c 192.168.0.12
Connecting to host 192.168.0.12, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.0.11 port 57756 connected to 192.168.0.12 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   180 MBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   180 MBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   180 MBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   181 MBytes  1.52 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   182 MBytes  1.53 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   184 MBytes  1.55 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   180 MBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   180 MBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   180 MBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   179 MBytes  1.50 Gbits/sec    0    426 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.77 GBytes  1.52 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.76 GBytes  1.51 Gbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.

~#@❯ /etc/init.d/iptables stop
 * Stopping Vuurmuur ...                                                   [ ok ]
 * Stopping Vuurmuur Log ...                                               [ ok ]
 * Saving iptables state ...                                               [ ok ]
 * Stopping firewall ...                                                   [ ok ]

~#@❯ iperf3 -c 192.168.0.12
Connecting to host 192.168.0.12, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.0.11 port 41346 connected to 192.168.0.12 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.37 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.37 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.37 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  1.09 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0    427 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  10.9 GBytes  9.38 Gbits/sec    0             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  2.00 GBytes  1.72 Gbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.

The iptables script:
export LAN=lan0
export WAN=wan

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -I INPUT 1 -i ${LAN} -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP --dport bootps ! -i ${LAN} -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP --dport domain ! -i ${LAN} -j REJECT

iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport ssh -i ${WAN} -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p TCP ! -i ${LAN} -d 0/0 --dport 0:1023 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP ! -i ${LAN} -d 0/0 --dport 0:1023 -j DROP

iptables -I FORWARD -i ${LAN} -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${LAN} -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ${WAN} -j MASQUERADE

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter ; do echo 1 > $f ; done


I fixed the problem, in the rules file /var/lib/iptables/rules-save the was a raw table rule for tun0 thousands of times repeated, don't know why, but that ultimately caused the slowdown.
Also strange why iptables -F did not clear it and why it did not appear when doing -L or -S.

"Also strange why iptables -F did not clear it and why it did not appear when doing -L or -S." iptables is not just one table, but many, including filter, nat, mangle, raw, and security. iptables only shows the filter table by default. The table you're looking for was probably nat, viewable by iptables -t nat -L.
